# CVS to Subversion Conversion: Diskspace Issue

Tags: svn, cvs, cvs2svn

Our current CVS repository has 42Gb of space. Truthfully, we'll probably not convert a lot of the stuff in there. However, let's assume we do and we keep the full history.

What would be the amount of space a Subversion repository would take up? I don't need an exact size -- just a ballpark figure.

For example, I believe that Subversion may take up a bit more space with text, but saves space with binaries. In the end, a Subversion version of this repository might take up (at a maximum) 60Gb of space, and not like 200Gb of space.

I'm doing an estimate for our new revision control system, and want to make sure I'm in the right ballpark. I'm thinking of requesting 200Gb of space. It's something I can get without too much trouble, but still provides more than enough room to grow. Since this will be its own system, there will be some OS files in this space.

Comment: I would expect the subversion repository to be equivalent or smaller - the file revisions are stored in more or less the same way but also compressed I think, and the extra metadata won't outweigh that. But I don't have any evidence for this. I wouldn't expect SVN to take more space for text, though - where did you get that from? It's usually that SVN checkouts (i.e. working copies) are larger than CVS checkouts that people worry about, not the repositories. You might also want to think about breaking your CVS into multiple SVN repositories too.

Comment: _I wouldn't expect SVN to take more space for text, though - where did you get that from?_. I am assuming better metadata, more indexing, etc. I'm not talking about orders of magnitude, but it wouldn't surprise me to see a 10% to 20% increase in space. The main concern is that 200Gb should be enough space to last for a few years.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conversion is finished. Subversion repositories appear to be about 10% bigger. We have plenty of space.